# Row selection by group and column conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, aggregate

I am trying to convert the dataframe on the left to the one on the right (seen below in the figure),

[image]

using conditions on further columns:

1. Block1 (top blue block): If Col4 has a lowest, but not repeating value within the group, then that row must be selected (row 5 in the example figure below)
2. Block2 (the second light green colour block from the top): If Col4 has the same value repeating, then the minimum value from Col5 plays a role. However, rows 9 and 10 have ties. To break the tie: rank-wise, the higher row or the last succeeding row must be selected (row 10 instead of 9, since 10 is greater than 9).
3. In the third block (red) from the top, Col4 has two 1s (lowest value in Col4) and correspondingly Col5 has two 2s. Since row 11 and 13 have ties now, rank-wise the higher row or the last succeeding row must be selected (row 13 instead of 11, since 13 is greater than 11).

The above logic continues for other blocks.

A tidyverse dplyr approach using slice,

```
DF <- Data_Frame %>% dplyr::group_by(Col1, Col2, Col3) %>% dplyr::slice(which.min(Col4))
```

produces the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

The dataframe used above is:

```
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), 
                         
                         Col2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h"),
                         
                         Col3 = c("Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Bb1","Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1"),
                         
                         Col4 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                         
                         Col5 = c(7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First group. then create rank with `row_number()`, `unite` `Col4` and `Col5`, then filter

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% 
  mutate(r_nr = row_number()) %>% 
  unite(Col45, c(Col4, Col5), sep="", remove=FALSE) %>% 
  filter(Col45 == min(Col45)) %>% 
  slice_max(r_nr) %>% 
  select(-Col45, -r_nr)
```

output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4  Col5
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1    a     Aa1       1     1
2 A1    b     Aa1       4     1
3 A1    c     Aa1       1     2
4 A1    d     Aa1       3     1
5 A2    e     Bb1       1     2
6 A2    f     Bb1       2     1
7 A3    g     Cc1       1     1
8 A3    h     Cc1       1     2
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"
), Col2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "g", 
"g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h"), Col3 = c("Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", 
"Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", 
"Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Aa1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", "Bb1", 
"Bb1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1", "Cc1"), Col4 = c(4, 
2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), Col5 = c(7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

Comment: This exactly does the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Ray , I believe that you are looking to summaries your data frame with minimum values, however your 3rd point was very confusing both seems to me as minimum values , however I ran the following code and the result came fine with me,

```
df %>% group_by(Col1,Col2,Col3) %>% summarise(Col4 = min(Col4),Col5 = min(Col5))
```

Comment: dear, did you try my code ? are you experiencing any error? thanks

Comment: The code works fine, but I am just wondering whether the right rows are selected based on row indices.

Comment: The data frame you posted is a bit of help now, let me re evaluate , I'll share incase I find something convincing to you

Comment: Yes, I did try your code. Thank you for it. My point is, in block 2, out of rows 9 and 10, 10 must be selected. And in block 3, out of rows 11 and 13, 13 must be selected. Does it select 9 and 11 rather than 10 and 13 (expected)? May be row indices play a role in ranking and selection?